# Joomla Accessing getModules datastructure

Tags: php, joomla

From this

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'top' );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $modules );
echo '</pre>';
```

which outputs this structure

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [title] => Newsflash
            [module] => mod_newsflash
            [position] => top
            [content] => 
            [showtitle] => 1
            [control] => 
            [params] => catid=3
style=random
items=
moduleclass_sfx=
            [user] => 0
            [name] => newsflash
            [style] => 
        )

)
```

I currently call this function to get it to output it

```
<?=$modules[0]->content ?>
```

I would like to call with one line but it doesnt work

```
<?=JModuleHelper::getModules( 'top' )[0]->content ?>
```

I can do it on the singular version of getmodule and it works, it works because its not wrapped in an array.

```
<?=JModuleHelper::getModule( 'top' )->content ?>
```

Anybody know how to drill down on this data structure with one line of code?

Comment: Have you tried `reset(JModuleHelper::getModules( 'top' ))->content`?

Comment: ok. I'll post it with some further explanation for other.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `reset()` resets the internal pointer of the array and returns the first element.
Therefore,

```
$modules = reset(JModuleHelper::getModules( 'top' ))->content;
```

will get the first element's content.

This **will** fail, however, if an empty array is returned by `JModuleHelper`, for obvious reasons. Unfortunately, it will not fail quietly, since `reset()` returns `false` when provided with an empty array.